# Understanding how R assigns plots as objects

Tags: r, object, ggplot2, plot, assign

I see lots of posts that are tangential to my question here, but not quite hitting the mark.  Sorry if I missed the solutions elsewhere.

I noticed that R seems to assign different types of plots as different types of objects or as NULL, but I'm not sure why.  Can you help me unpack this?  The goal is to simply save the plot as an object that can be displayed later in various markdown files, but I don't need anything more complicated than a basic print--no lattices, etc.

For example

```
# Toy data setup 
set.seed(63)
d <- rnorm(100)
```

Basic histogram doesn't show when calling the object alone, but does when wrapped in a plot() function.

```
hist(d)       # works as expected
p1 <- hist(d) # saves as a "List of 6" with class "histogram"
p1; print(p1) # both print all data in the list but no histogram plot
plot(p1)      # shows histogram plot
```

Variation using the plot function saves as NULL

```
plot(d, type="h") # works as expected
p2 <- plot(d) # saves as "NULL (empty)"
p2; print(p2) # both print NULL as expected given how it saved
plot(p2)      # generates error message, as expected
```

The ggplot approach also saves and works as expected

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot() +aes(d) + geom_histogram()  # works as expected with message info
p3 <- ggplot() +aes(d) + geom_histogram()  # saves as "List of 9" with class "gg" and "ggplot"
p3  # shows histogram as expected
```

So 3 different ways to show a basic histogram(like) plot and all behave differently when trying to assign the plot as an object to call later.  Even hist() and ggplot() as saved as objects show differently when called even though they both save as lists.

What am I missing?

To make things a bit more complicated, I noticed that if I overlap plots, as with the histograms below, into a single plot, the assigned object does not contain both plots.  I could see this also being useful for saving fit lines, added point or text, etc.

What do I need to do to save plot additions to the plot object?
The following example code comes from [R Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/overlapping-histogram-in-r/).

```
#Random numbers
h2<-rnorm(1000,4)
h1<-rnorm(1000,6)
# Histogram Colored (blue and red)
hist(h1, col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5),xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,200), main="Overlapping Histogram", xlab="Variable")
hist(h2, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5), add=T)
```

They work as expected.  However, if I join them with a semicolon after assigning the first to an object, the first histograms modifications are gone and the overlapping histogram is missing.  It makes sense the overlapping histogram is gone since the second command is not actually applied to the saved histogram object, but I'm curious how to add it.

Comment: `hist` *always* returns something: a named `list` with certain objects in it. You don't see it all the time because it is often `invisible(...)`. Some plotting functions return things, others return `NULL`. Nothing in base-R (afaicr) returns a plot-object, normally they return nothing or a list or vector or frame. (This is opposed to `ggplot2` which always returns a grob.) Once you start combining plots (`layout`, `par(mfrow)`, or `add=TRUE`), then all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans .  Looks like I need to learn much more about how R fundamentally handles things.

Comment: @r2evans I'd mark your comment as an answer if I could, but from what I know about SO, I cannot do that with comments.  If you repost as an answer, I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions with the side-effect of creating a graphic plot may or may not return something. With the `ggplot2` package, for instance, it returns a complex list structure with enough information and pre-defined attributes that either (1) `print`ing it will result in a graphic object ("grob"), or (2) more layers can be added or attributes changed to this list-structure. As an example,

```r
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_point()
str(gg, max.level=1)
# List of 9
#  $ data       :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ layers     :List of 1
#  $ scales     :Classes 'ScalesList', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class ScalesList, gg>
#     add: function
#     clone: function
#     find: function
#     get_scales: function
#     has_scale: function
#     input: function
#     n: function
#     non_position_scales: function
#     scales: list
#     super:  <ggproto object: Class ScalesList, gg> 
#  $ mapping    :List of 2
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "uneval"
#  $ theme      : list()
#  $ coordinates:Classes 'CoordCartesian', 'Coord', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord, gg>
#     aspect: function
#     backtransform_range: function
#     clip: on
#     default: TRUE
#     distance: function
#     expand: TRUE
#     is_free: function
#     is_linear: function
#     labels: function
#     limits: list
#     modify_scales: function
#     range: function
#     render_axis_h: function
#     render_axis_v: function
#     render_bg: function
#     render_fg: function
#     setup_data: function
#     setup_layout: function
#     setup_panel_params: function
#     setup_params: function
#     transform: function
#     super:  <ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord, gg> 
#  $ facet      :Classes 'FacetNull', 'Facet', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class FacetNull, Facet, gg>
#     compute_layout: function
#     draw_back: function
#     draw_front: function
#     draw_labels: function
#     draw_panels: function
#     finish_data: function
#     init_scales: function
#     map_data: function
#     params: list
#     setup_data: function
#     setup_params: function
#     shrink: TRUE
#     train_scales: function
#     vars: function
#     super:  <ggproto object: Class FacetNull, Facet, gg> 
#  $ plot_env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#  $ labels     :List of 2
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
```

"Just a `list`."

Non-grid graphic functions *sometimes* employ a similar strategy. For instance, `hist` always returns a named `list`; if you use the default `plot=TRUE`, then it returns this list *invisibly* and one side-effect is the creation of a plot. With `hist(..., plot=FALSE)`, however, the `list` is returned visibly and no plot is created. Similar to `ggplot2`'s S3 method for `print` (`ggplot2:::print.ggplot2` and friends), there is an S3 method for `hist`'s return object (class `histogram`), named `graphics:::plot.histogram`, so if you do

```r
h <- hist(mtcars$disp, plot = FALSE)
str(h)
# List of 6
#  $ breaks  : int [1:10] 50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500
#  $ counts  : int [1:9] 5 7 4 1 4 4 4 1 2
#  $ density : num [1:9] 0.003125 0.004375 0.0025 0.000625 0.0025 ...
#  $ mids    : num [1:9] 75 125 175 225 275 325 375 425 475
#  $ xname   : chr "mtcars$disp"
#  $ equidist: logi TRUE
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

then a simple `plot(h)` will generate the plot. (Even if you plot it the first time with the default of `h <- hist(..., plot=TRUE)`, you can regenerate the plot later with `plot(h)`.)

But not all plotting functions or their accessory functions return something. `lines` and `points`, for instance, always return `NULL`. You cannot "capture" the output from `lines` and (re)apply it later.

But as far as I can tell, no base R function "returns" a plot object. `grid` functions might, specifically those that modify grobs.

If you want to "save" a plot itself (and not the `list` or components used to create it), then look into [`?recordPlot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/recordplot.html), which can be run immediately after any base graphics function (including the accessory functions `lines`, `points`, etc).